# Alfresco web service authentication api/dictionary

Tags: alfresco

I have two separate servers for alfresco and share. I can successfully login from share to alfresco. I can also change my password too. But when opening Repository Browser page, I got
this error message.

```
11210005 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js': 11210004 11210008 Failed to run action evaluator: 11210007 Failed processing dictionary information from Alfresco: 11210006 Unable to retrieve dictionary information from Alfresco: 500
```

Full stack trace is

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 11210008 Failed to run action evaluator: 11210007 Failed processing dictionary information from Alfresco: 11210006 Unable to retrieve dictionary information from Alfresco: 500
    at org.alfresco.web.evaluator.NodeTypeEvaluator.evaluate(NodeTypeEvaluator.java:98)
    at org.alfresco.web.evaluator.BaseEvaluator.evaluate(BaseEvaluator.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c4(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js:260)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c2(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js:318)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c20(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js:838)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c0(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js:854)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.exec(file:/D:/alfrescoplatform/development/apache-tomcat-share_ref/webapps/share_ref1/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/data/surf-doclist.get.js)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.processor.JSScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(JSScriptProcessor.java:318)
    ... 39 more
```

So I trace NodeTypeEvaluator and DictionaryQuery class in deep.I found calling `/api/dictionary` from alfresco.

I try [this](http://stuffandnothing.com/index.php/2009/04/08/accessing-remote-alfresco-web-services/). Adding

```
webserviceclient.properties
repository.location=http://hostname:8080/alfresco/api
```

in share, but no success.

In calling **http://hostname:8080/alfresco/api/** shows

```
Axis HTTP Servlet
Hi, you have reached the AXIS HTTP Servlet. Normally you would be hitting this URL with a SOAP client rather than a browser.

In case you are interested, my AXIS transport name appears to be 'http
```

Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: I run Alfresco and Share almost always on different application server, you just need to change the share-config-custom.xml and alfresco-global.properties for it. There is a How-To on the Alfresco forums. Have you followed it?

Comment: Can you give me a link for how-to??

Comment: https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=34725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As accepted in the comment the answer for this question:
I run Alfresco and Share almost always on different application server, you just need to change the share-config-custom.xml and alfresco-global.properties for it. There is a [How-To](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=34725) on the Alfresco forums. Have you followed it?